# Convert dd/mm/yyyy string to Unix timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In my table I have a varchar column called `date` containing string representations of dates in dd/mm/yyyy format. How can I convert these to Unix times in a SELECT query?

Comment: You *probably* shouldn't be storing dates as dd/mm/yyyy strings in the first place. MySQL has a [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/datetime.html) type for storing dates; you should always use that to represent dates unless you have a good reason to do otherwise. *If* you were doing that, then you'd be able to get your Unix timestamp by just doing `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) FROM yourtable`. Since you're not storing your dates as dates in the first place, though, there's an extra conversion step (shown in the accepted answer) which makes things just a little more complicated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
select unix_timestamp(str_to_date('30/05/2011','%d/%m/%Y'));
```

or:

```
select unix_timestamp(str_to_date(myfield,'%d/%m/%Y')) from mytable;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think UNIX_TIMESTAMP should do the trick. Can you specify your select query here?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: Here is what I did select unix_timestamp(str_to_date('date','%d/%m/%Y')) from tbl; Where date is column name. And the result is null

Answer (score 0):

just use `unix_timestamp` function