# Selecting items from a database that are newer than 6 months?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got events in a database that have a Unix timestamp (ex: 1350450000).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM events");
```

I need to select the items that are newer than 6 months from the current date including anything scheduled after the current date. I've been messing around with several ways to do this, but no luck getting anything to work.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM events WHERE monthyear >= ...?");
```

I know I should avoid `mysql_*` functions, but the entire site has been coded with it and I'm just making the minor changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178477/convert-to-unix-timestamp-mysql

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT ... WHERE stampColumn > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 180)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **strtotime** PHP function to get a timestamp representing 6 months back time and use it in the query:

```
$ts = strtotime("-6 month");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM events WHERE monthyear >= {$ts}");
```